# How to write python script to read two excel worksheets and delete any repeats in one if both have values?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 worksheets in excel. They both contain 3 columns a,b and c. I need to delete any row in worksheet 1 if the data items for columns a,b,c are the same between the two worksheets. How would I do this using the Pandas python library?

```
import pandas as pd
ws1 = pd.read_excel(pathname/worksheet1.xlsx)
ws2 = pd.read_excel(pathname/worksheet2.xlsx)
```

Basically `worksheet1` looks something like this (dummy numbers assume they're different in actual data):

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
1   2   3   4   4   4
1   2   3   4   4   4
1   2   3   4   4   4
1   2   3   4   4   4
1   2   3   4   4   4
```

`worksheet2` looks something like this:

```
a   b   f   d   e   c
1   2   4   4   4   3
1   2   4   4   4   3
1   2   4   4   4   3
1   2   4   4   4   3
1   2   4   4   4   3
```

I have to check columns a,b and c in `worksheet1` and if the same data shows up in `worksheet2`, I would delete that row in `worksheet1`.

For example, in `worksheet1` the values 1,2 and 3 are returned for columns a,b and c. I need to check if 1,2 and 3 show up in columns a,b and c in `worksheet2` (located differently). If they do show up in `worksheet2`, I need to delete the row in `worksheet1` with the values 1,2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assuming that worksheets list1 and list 2 - two separate excel files):

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('/path/to/file_name1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('/path/to/file_name2.xlsx')

df1 = df1[~df1.email.isin(df2.email)]
```

The third line of code removes those rows from `df1` which are found in the `df2` (assuming that the column name is `email` in both DFs)

Comment: by df do you mean dataframe? And if so why are we creating a dataframe?

Comment: @mobcityzkore, yes, `df` - Data Frame. You wanted to do it using Pandas library, correct? Working with Pandas means working with DataFrames (or with Panels - it might be deprecated in future).

Comment: cool! Assuming my excel worksheets have thousands of entries how can I test to see that it actually worked? I plugged in dummy values in the appropriate columns with the same email in both, saved the files then ran the code. When I opened them again, it did not show the files(df1) as having been edited.

Comment: ok so I used a to_excel line to save it. It looks like its working :) If there is a better way, let me know!